# standard js, flow type defintions always undefined

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype

I have a small issue with a boilerplate I'm setting up currently, I'm using Flow JS to type define my javascript for my react application, in the bacground i have a standard js running, but it is not playing nicely with my type notations

I keep getting the following warning on this type definition:

```
type NavItem = {
  name: string;
  link: string;
}
```

The warning

```
frontend/src/Components/Sidebar/Navigation.react.js:5:6: 'NavItem' is not defined.
```

what am i doing wrong, this is my config for standard js

```
"standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [ "flowtype" ],
    "rules": {
      "use-flow-type": 1
    },
    "ignore": [
      "flow-typed/**/*.js",
      "src/registerServiceWorker.js"
    ]
  },
```

If any one has any suggestions i would love them, im based out of the create-react-app cli tool if it makes any diffrence for you aswell :)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this @Nopzen?

Comment: Nope :) Still open for suggestions.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: To be honest, i haven't had the time to come around to this, be see the answer below, @morganfree seems to have a fix, but downgrading is not something that i like, since im hitting this issue in the create react app boilerplate, and i dont feel like ejecting my entire project.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open ticket in standardjs repo: [#984](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/984) - it is related to that issue.

As a workaround you can downgrade to `babel-eslint@7.2.1` and wait for the fix. The downgrade worked for me with the exact same problem.

You can also try to edit standardjs rules - see: [babel-eslint#known-issues](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint#known-issues) and [eslint-config-standard](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard).

Comment: This worked for me using webstorm + standard linter. Standard was giving me all kinds of problems with Flow- this Fixed it! Thank you! Thought I was gonna have to switch to Typescript for my whole project!!